# Why would Spotify embed fail to load in an iframe but work in a standalone tab?

Tags: javascript, iframe, proxy, spotify

I have a page with an embedded Spotify playlist in an iframe. Noticed yesterday that the iframe was failing to load for some users who are on a proxied workplace internet connection. My first thought was that spotify had been blocked, but now I'm not so sure.

- The iframe has src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/playlist/{playlist_id}". This was not working on the workplace connection, but *was* working on any other internet connection.
- While on the proxied network, I tried just opening up that url in a new tab. This worked fine, which suggests to me that theres no firewall or domain filtering going on.
- I changed the url to "https://embed.spotify.com/playlist/{playlist_id}", not thinking it would work, but it did! It just 302 redirects back to the original open.spotify.com url, but this allowed the iframe to load without error.
- The next problem was that the 'embed' subdomain didn't recognise that a user might be logged in to spotify, so it only showed preview version of the player. So I tried switching the URL back to 'open.spotify.com' AFTER the iframe had first loaded the 'embed.spotify.com' URL. Again, I didn't expect this to work, but it actually did.

Anyone wiser than me know what's going on here? Is this an issue with Spotify, or with the network? Or with me?

Comment: when using iframe from scenario to scenario, depending the circumstances it might happen that it excludes everything of the contents from the surroundings, try to avoid the use of iframes the most possible, wrap or dynamically load desired content with either vanilla javascript or use reactive framework

Comment: It could be a little bit of everything, so if you can remove at least one factor `e.g, iframe`  at a time things might get more robust and resilient, start by googling things for 'html iframe user sessions or state issues' and judge by yourself.

trust more in your instincts when things start getting whacky, one suggestion is to keep in mind there are times that 'less is more', be super simple.